# Running gcloud test locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pytest, google-cloud-build

I have a pre-commit hook setup to run a test suite for a Google Cloud Storage api. I can simulate a Google Build and run the tests fine `cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --dryrun=false .`. However, when running the pre-commit hook, I get the error

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started`

Sample `google_cloud_api.py` function

```
def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Returns list of names of all the blobs in the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
    return [blob.name for blob in blobs]
```

Sample `test_google_cloud_api.py` function

```
def test_get_all_files():
    blobs = google_cloud_storage_api.list_blobs(GCS_BUCKET_NAME)
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob)
```

Comment: How do you run pre-commit hook?

Comment: @CloudAce By using a `pre-commit-config.yaml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a service account and download the json file, set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to that file

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service/account.json
```

Or use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```